# Ado Entity update doesn't work

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I am using ado entity model with designer in visual studio 2012. When I create it there is model.edmx which contains contex.tt, desinger.cs, diagram and model.tt, i also saw that after i use desinger and map few tables, it creates files for each table, separate file for each table but those files are not visible in project only exist in solution direction in model folder.

Now, the problem is that when I modify sth in sql , and then update view of this model in model.edmx i have **terrible problem**, each time, those files per table in model directory are **NOT changed**, each time I do small changes to put those changes into model, **i have to remove whole edmx and create again**. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update all the changes you have made in your model. just Right Click the model and `Run Custom Tool`.  See the image below: 
 
 [image]

Comment: trust me, it doesn't help.

Comment: actually we're the same encountered problem, but in this "Run Custom Tool" it's my way to update all the changes i made from my model.